# How to send data between two already configured HC-05 modules

Tags: bluetooth, pi-pico, communication, micropython

I'm new to electronics and microcontrollers, and I'm building an small project in which I'd like to send information from a master HC-05 bluetooth module to an slave one, I've already synced them following [Bluetooth HC-05 master-slave configuration using CircuitPython](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2022/05/31/bluetooth-hc-05-master-slave-configuration-using-circuitpython/) tutorial, I've finished the set up and now both modules (master and slave) seem to be properly connected, now the problem is that I don't know how to send data from one to the other.

All the tutorials that I've found that imply bluetooth communication seem to do it from a mobile Android app to the slave module, but what I'd like to do is to read data from an analog joystick with one pi pico and send it through my master HC-05 to the slave module (which would be connected to another pico) and then control an electric motor with this received data.

As I understand, the configuration process was finished in CircuitPython but this DOES NOT obligate me to continue with CircuitPython, I mean, I could do my implementation with microPython for example, is this correct?

My main question is, what is the library/process I could use to send data from master module to slave module?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for libraries.

On the Pico with the joystick you write to the joystick data to the connected HC-05 and on the other Pico you read the serial data from the connected HC-05.

All this is just plain serial communication.

And is has no relevance witch HC-05 is slave or master, thats only relevant when pairing them.

Comment: Thank you @MatsK, after reading about this issue I could find a way to read the data received by the slave HC05 (which seems to work), now the problem is that I don't know how to send data from master to slave; after a while I found this MycroPython class: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.UART.html , I tried to use `uart.write(data)` but it doesn't seem to reach the slave module, would you please tell me if I'm taking a good approach ?

Comment: Forget about it, I restarted my boards and it worked, but thanks for your initial guiding!